# Replace MAX value with 1 (else = 0) rowwise in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with a lot of colums, how can I replace the values with either (1 or 0) given that the MAX value per row gets a 1 and all others 0. So if I have

```
v1 v2 v3
1  3  2
0  4  .5
.1 .1 .7
```

And get:

```
v1 v2 v3
0  1  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

Numbers are floats, given previous calculations NO duplicate numbers per row are possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do `max` then `eq`

```
df=df.eq(df.max(axis=1),axis=0).astype(int)
   v1  v2  v3
0   0   1   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
```